# How to move items in a numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I haven't found a simple solution to move elements in a NumPy array.

Given an array, for example:

```py
>>> A = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

and given the indexes of the elements (columns in this case) to move, for example `[2,4]`, I want to move them to a certain position and the consecutive places, for example to `p = 1`, shifting the other elements to the right. The result should be the following:

```py
array([[0, 2, 4, 1, 3],
       [5, 7, 9, 6, 8]])
```

Comment: Make a new array using the appropriate column indexing.

Comment: `A[:,[0,2,4,1,2,3]]`?

Comment: yes, but then it is the same problem with the indexes. How can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask `m` for the sorting order. First we set the columns < `p` to `-1`, then the to be inserted columns to `0`, the remaining columns remain at `1`. The default sorting kind  `'quicksort'` is not stable, so to be safe we specify `kind='stable'` when using [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to sort the mask and create a new array from that mask:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
p = 1
c = [2,4]

m = np.full(A.shape[1], 1)
m[:p] = -1    # leave up to position p as is
m[c] = 0      # insert columns c

print(A[:,m.argsort(kind='stable')])
#[[0 2 4 1 3]
# [5 7 9 6 8]]
```

Comment: I think quicksort is not stable.

Comment: @DiegoPalacios yes, my bad. I updated the answer.